# How to check if a column contains backslash

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = {'value': ['red','red\blue','yellow']
}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['value'])
```

I tried to use:

```
df[df['value'].str.contains("\\", na = False)]['value'].count()
```

but got the error:

```
bad escape (end of pattern) at position 0
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: does this work? `df['value'].str.contains("\\",na=False,regex=False)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data was change for avoid `\b` value, add `r` prefix because by default `regex=True`.
For count is simplier use `sum` of `True`s values:

```
data = {'value': ['red','red\ blue','yellow']}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['value'])
print(df)
       value
0        red
1  red\ blue
2     yellow

print (df['value'].str.contains(r"\\", na = False).sum())
1
```

Another idea is avoid regexes by `regex=False` parameter in [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
print (df['value'].str.contains("\\", na = False, regex=False).sum())
1
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you just need to precede `r` in the code you are showing:

```
df[df['value'].str.contains(r"\\", na = False)]['value'].count()
```

This will work because, from [documentation](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html):

> Unless an ‘r’ or ‘R’ prefix is present, escape sequences in strings are interpreted according to rules similar to those used by Standard C

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating the df.value Series

```
>>> df.value
0        red
1    relue
2     yellow
Name: value, dtype: object
>>>
```

Note df.value[1] shows the value of **relue** since it evaluate \b as a back space
Using the raw method on 'red\blue'

```
data = {'value': ['red',r'red\blue','yellow']}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['value'])

>>>print (df.value.str.contains("\\", na = False, regex=False).sum())
1
>>>
```